# Facebook post- open graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a fan page which requires the open graph meta tags of facebook. Everything works fine. posting on timeline, tagging of friends and places etc. but the post which gets posted has the main heading like

"{User} visted a {action} on {App name} - with {Tagged Friend} at {Tagged Place}"

but i want "in" instead of "at" before {Tagged Place}

Can someone help me out. Sorry for the weak explanation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use actions from fan page unless you are running an app.

If you have custom action you can select which term to use. I think the correct syntax is 
(user) (action) (object) on (app name). Maybe you should revisit the facebook action API and make sure your app is setup correctly.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/